# How to animate a deletion in GoJS when removing node data?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I am trying to animate the deletion of nodes in a diagram

I'm using this piece of code from the GoJS docs:
https://gojs.net/latest/intro/animation.html

```
myDiagram.addDiagramListener('SelectionDeleting', function(e) {
  // the DiagramEvent.subject is the collection of Parts about to be deleted
  e.subject.each(function(part) {
    if (!(part instanceof go.Node)) return; // only animate Nodes
    var animation = new go.Animation();
    var deletePart = part.copy();
    animation.add(deletePart, "scale", deletePart.scale, 0.01);
    animation.add(deletePart, "angle", deletePart.angle, 360);
    animation.addTemporaryPart(deletePart, myDiagram);
    animation.start();
  });
});
```

[image]

To delete a node I am using `myDiagram.model.removeNodeData(node)`, but this is not triggering the event. If i delete the node manually using the `Del` key it works.

How can I trigger the event when using code to delete a node, like when using `myDiagram.model.removeNodeData(node)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, `myDiagram.model.removeNodeData(node)` won't call that event. So you need the code that calls `myDiagram.model.removeNodeData(node)` to call the same code as the event.

So take the code out and put it into its own function, for more general use:

```js
function animateDeletion(part) {
  if (!(part instanceof go.Node)) return; // only animate Nodes
  var animation = new go.Animation();
  var deletePart = part.copy();
  animation.add(deletePart, "scale", deletePart.scale, 0.01);
  animation.add(deletePart, "angle", deletePart.angle, 360);
  animation.addTemporaryPart(deletePart, myDiagram);
  animation.start();
}

myDiagram.addDiagramListener('SelectionDeleting', function(e) {
  // the DiagramEvent.subject is the collection of Parts about to be deleted
  e.subject.each(function(part) {
    animateDeletion(part);
  });
});
```

Then you can call that same code before you call removeNodeData:

```js
  // ... elsewhere...
  animateDeletion(node);
  myDiagram.model.removeNodeData(node.data);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using the method `myDiagram.model.findNodeDataForKey('foo')` to get the node but it returned an ObjectData instead of a Node object.  `if (!(part instanceof go.Node)) return;` was stopping the function. But I got it working using `myDiagram.nodes` and searching for the node I wanted to delete.

Comment: You can always use `myDiagram.findNodeForKey('foo')` instead to get the node: https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#findNodeForKey